# flutter image upload doesnt work on real device altough It works on emulator

Tags: php, image, api, flutter, upload

here is the function I use to upload images to database. It works properly on emulator but when I try to do it using my real device it doesnt work.(I allowed internet permission)

```
  Future uploadImage() async {

  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var userimidd = sharedPreferences.getString('id');
  DateTime now = DateTime.now().toLocal();
  String tarih = "${now.day}_${now.month}_${now.year}:${now.hour + 3}:${now.minute}";

  final uri = Uri.parse("http://MY IP/uploadavatar.php");
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
  request.fields['userid'] = userimidd;
  String allofthem = '${userimidd}__${now.day}_${now.month}_${now.year}_${now.minute}_${now.second}_${now.microsecond}.jpg';
  request.fields['useravatarextension'] = allofthem;
  var pic = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("image",_image.path,filename: allofthem);
  request.files.add(pic);
  var response = await request.send();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Image successfully uploaded');
  } else {
    print('Something bad happened');
  }
}
```

And here is my api source;

```
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$useravatarextension = $_POST['useravatarextension'];




$imagePath = 'uploads/'.$image;
$tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$imagePath);

$db->query("UPDATE users SET user_picture = 'http://MY IP/uploads/$useravatarextension' WHERE userid = '".$userid."'");
```

The second code ($db-> query) works but it doesnt upload...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue and found out the issue is with the image size(As image size of real device is large).so tell your backend team to handle the image size.

Comment: thanks dude, I was both dealing with backend and frontend. I went into PHP.ini and set the maximum upload size from 2 MB to 40MB :D It worked

Answer (score 0):

Add an alse condition ie

```
if(response.statuscode == 200)
{
  // print(result)
}
else
{
  print(response.statucode)
}
```

Then run in device. Take a note of the Error Status Code. From that we can debug the issue that is causing the same.